# Pin / Fix div in Javascript on scroll with parallax

Tags: javascript, wordpress, parallax, scrollmagic

I am trying to pin an div for a certain amount when you start scrolling the page.

I would like this because I have a slider (revolution slider in Wordpress) with an parallax effect and want to be able to display some items that start to show when you scroll down.

I have tried to implement ScrollMagic javascript but was not able to achieve any results.

It could be that I am wrong here and not use the parallax effect. I have seen other websites using the `transform: scale();` and `transform: translate3d();` but that would mean I have to create my own slider to say so.

If someone can point me in de right direction that would be very helpful.

Greetings,
Mark

Comment: have you tried background-attachment:fixed

Comment: The background would be fixed but not the whole DIV by itself. The slider needs to stay for a while so the other (parallax) layers can move.
After that you should be able to see the rest of the content.

Comment: have you tried something so far?

Comment: I tried implementing ScrollMagic, tried the transform translat3d and now looking into scroll offset. But nothing looks promising or is not giving me the results I am looking for.